# SCTE 35 ad markers in transport streams

Tags: ads, ott, scte-35

I have few doubts on SCTE-35 markers.

1. Is there any open source tools available to add splice points to mpeg segments. Currently I am using mpddash and mp4hls for converting fragmented mp4 into mpd/hls. Please help where and how can I add SCTE markers.
2. Can I add SCTE markers to mp4 file?
3. As per my understanding, to dynamically add advertise a content segments must have some splice points previously added to it.  With the help of an ESAM script the splice points are replaced with actual advertise with a live transcoder.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

In SCTE 35 [standard](https://wagtail-prod-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/SCTE_35_2022.pdf) it is mentioned to splice_insert() etc. commands. Is there any tools available where these commands can be applied to mpeg segments?

In short I want to understand, how can I add scte 35 markers to vod content?

Comment: I don't know of a DASH or HLS tool but this one exists for MPEG TS streams: https://github.com/tsduck/tsduck. You can use packagers like AWS Media Package and Unified Streaming etc to insert them also and you can usually get a trial version or account to try it out on.